# group permissions for scp

Tags: linux, scp, chmod, umask

We have a server running as a `firebird` user.  We want to `scp` files to the server that are need by firebird but copied as another user: `it-test`.

What is the best way to set that up on the server-side so only the `firebird` user and the  `it-test` user can access the file copied?  The destination is always the same folder.

Something like this:

`sudo setfacl -m u:firebird:r /opt/firebird/extern`

That command did not work however (`Operation not supported`).  I think that is for files only...

Comment: I have `setfacl` installed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need then set the parent folder to `0770`, owned by `firebird:somegroup`. `it-test` and `firebird` should be in `somegroup`.

Then set the parent folder to be owned by `somegroup` and set the [`setgid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) bit on it. This will result in all subfolders and files owned by the parent folder owner group, not their creator group.

Finally upload all files as 0660, folders as 0770. This will result in both users being able to read and modify the files.